# C# XPathSelectElement to find element with a specific value

Tags: c#, xpath

I want to query for an element

```
<Identifier>var1</Identifier>
```

inside another element, and the namespace of var1 is 
http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/07/AppServer/Transforms.

I used the statement `element.XPathSelectElement({"'//{http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/07/AppServer/Transforms}Identifier[=var1]');`

`"{http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/07/AppServer/Transforms}Identifier"` is the toString() returned value from the XName for Identifier.

XPathSelectElement is throwing the below exception:

> {"'//{http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/07/AppServer/Transforms}Identifier[=var1]'
>   has an invalid token."}
>   .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no integration for XName and XPath, either use LINQ to XML methods e.g.

```
  element.Descendants(yourXNameVar + "Identifier").FirstOrDefault(el => el.Value == "var1")
```

or use the XPath approach with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351355.aspx e.g.

```
  XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
  mgr.AddPrefix("df", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/07/AppServer/Transforms");
  element.XPathSelectElement("//df:Identifier[. = 'var1']", mgr);
```